# Yellowing effect on Canon Rebel

Tags: lighting, white-balance, canon-500d

I've started to notice a strong yellowing of the indoor pictures with my Canon Rebel T1i. If I use the flash, this doesn't happen, but I don't want to have to use the flash on every picture as this really annoys people. Did I do something wrong to the camera?

Comment: Is the entire image yellow or just part of it?

Comment: It's pretty much the whole picture. It seems to get worse as the light gets stronger.

Comment: if it is appearing as a band of light, then it is most likely florescent lights cycling.  Florescent lights do not output a constant white light, but rather cycle through a very yellow phase.  If you are taking photos under the cycle frequency of your power, then part of the exposure may only catch the yellow portion of the frequency.  The faster you make the shutter, the more pronounced the effect will become.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's the lights indoor, they're usually "warmer" and that lends a color cast to images that the camera can normally compensate for. What you want to look for is the "white balance" settings for your camera. I suspect that yours has been set on "Flash" rather than "Auto".

The manual, if you don't have it, is [available online](http://gdlp01.c-wss.com/gds/6/0300002246/01/eosrti-eos500d-imh-en.pdf). Page 96 should have the info.

You can, once you know this, set your camera according to the lighting any time you want. For the most part, auto is usually okay.

Comment: It may be worth shooting a couple of shots in RAW and then playing about with white balance in post-process - this will give you a good feel as to how these settings work.

Comment: I had it on auto white balance. Changing to custom and taking a few practice shots really helped clean up the pictures. I'm wondering if part of the problem was having someone in a white shirt in the picture.

Comment: @Phoenix14830 - White balance in the camera is based on the scene, so it can be fooled and older cameras are even more susceptible to it. If you know what the dominate light is, then you can just pick it. If you shoot in RAW format, then you can pick it after the fact and not lose anything.

Comment: JoanneC: Thank you. That would explain why the editing software on the PC was so successful cleaning up the picture.